# The first, the third and the fifth term of an AP are the first, the second and the sixth term of a GP, respectively

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The first, the third and the fifth term of a GP are the first, the second and the sixth term of an AP, respectively. Find the common ratio of the GP.

Let $a_1, a_2=a_1q, a_3=a_1q^2...$ be in G.P. and $b_1, b_2=b_1+d,...$ be in AP.

I tried to solve the system $$\begin{cases}a_1=b_1\\a_3=a_1q^2=b_2=b_1+d\\a_5=a_1q^4=b_6=b_1+5d\end{cases}$$ and from here to solve for the common ratio, but I wasn't able to. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, $a_5-a_3=4(a_3-a_1)$. So, $a_1q^4-a_1q^2=4(a_1q^2-a_1)$. If $a_1=0$, $q$ can be anything. Otherwise, $q^4-5q^2+4=0$, So $(q^2-4)(q^2-1)=0$, so $q=\pm2,\pm1$ are the only possibilities. Test them out and see which one works (hint: 2 of them work, so the solution is not unique).

Comment: @DonThousand, Thank you for the response! how did you get the first equation?

Comment: I agree with your equations.  Further, you are only being asked to solve for $q$.  You have, from these equations that $$a_1(q^2 - 1) = d$$ and $$a_1(q^4 - 1) = 5d.$$  This gives $$\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^2 - 1} = 5.$$  This last equation translates into an easily solvable quadratic equation in $(q^2).$

Comment: Re my previous comment, the possibility of $q^2=1$ and/or $a_1=0$ needs special consideration.